# call php script from another php script multiple time

Tags: php

i have this code for read some data from a database, and call another php script (hostes on another server) for sending retrieved data. this is my code:

```
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($quary_result)) {
    $fields = array(
        'field1' => $rs['field1']
    );

    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

but this code is executed only once. My query as about 200 results, while is executed only one time. What's wrong?

Comment: first of all where is `$url` var? Second, why do you use mysql_* functions? you MUST know they are deprecated... My advice: switch to PDO and `foreach()` them...

Comment: is declared in my code. But that's not the problem, because script is called perfectly, but only once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the impression that it is executed only once...

Your code says this:

```
while $rs = mysql_fetch_array($query_result) is true { do something }
```

Then the `$result` var will be overwritten at each entering in the while loop. Try converting the $result var into an array of result and then print the array to see if you have all your values like:

```
$result[] = curl_exec($ch);
echo '<pre>';
   print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Also, you can use `foreach()` like:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
foreach ($result as $res) { do something }
```

AND STOP USING MYSQL - this is deprecated. Use PDO instead like you are thought in this tutorial: [PDO Tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).